# how to hide all child ComposteView of another CompositeView item?

Tags: tree, marionette

i need to hide all children of some item. the structure is a nested tree and to do that i'm using  CompositeView.  what should i do to make collapse in that tree works?

```
var ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  tagName : "li",
  //...,
  onRender: function () {
    this.collection = this.model.children; // bindCollection
  },
  serializeData: function() {
    //...
  },
  events: {
    "click .tree-view-chevron": 'toggleView'
  },
  toggleView: function() {
    this.$el.toggleClass("open");
    if (!this.$el.hasClass("open")) {
      //collapse then re-render parent collectionView
    }
    else
      this.render();
    this.switchChevron();
    return false;
  },
  switchChevron: function() {
    //...
  }
});

var TreeRoot = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  itemView : ItemView
  ,tagName: "ul"
  ,className: "tree-view-root"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i've just written the solution for my 'stupid' problem:

```
hideChildren: function() {
  this.children.each(
        function(itemV) { 
            itemV.$el.detach();
        }
  ); 
},
toggleView: function() {

  if (this.$el.hasClass("open"))
    {
        this.hideChildren();
        this.$el.removeClass("open");
        if (this.model.hasChildren()) 
            this.ui.chevron.html(this.chevronRight);
    }
  else
    {
        this.render();
        this.$el.addClass("open");
        if (this.model.hasChildren()) 
          this.ui.chevron.html(this.chevronDown);
    }

  return false;
}
```

the hideChildren!!! function and collapse on that tree works. but maybe there are some better way to do that... i'm new in js yet.